# tkMessageBox Crashes Python Application Upon Running

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tkmessagebox

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

def created():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('File Created!', 'Letter.html Created on Desktop')

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

# --- Everything Fine Here ---

        self.B = Tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Create Document', command = self.OnButtonClick)
        self.B.grid(column = 0, row = 6)


    def OnButtonClick(self):
        created()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Receipt Form')
    app.iconbitmap(os.getcwd() + '/M.tiff')
    app.mainloop()
```

I use py2app to create a standalone application with this, but when I run it and press the button, it seems to crash.

I am very certain it is tkMessageBox that is causing the problem but the message box works perfectly fine in IDLE.

It also worked fine on my Windows 10 computer with pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

py2exe is windows version of py2app.

first of all to build we need a setup file like this:

**[setup.py]**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe                      #in your case import py2app
setup(console=['myFile.py'])
```

on running this file using **python setup.py py2exe** :

it will call setup and tell it that we want a single console application and the main entry point is "**myFile.py**".

On complete build, two directories are created . Look into the dist directory and run your app.

It is working completely fine.

No errors

PS - make sure path to your icon is correct

[output screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZjKm.png)

Comment: I already have the setup.py and everything, but it is the module tkMessageBox that seems to crash the app. Once that button self.B is pressed, the app crashes.

Comment: It has to be some build issue. Working fine for me.

Comment: tkMessageBox on MacOSX with py2app with python 2.7?

Comment: tkMessageBox on win10 with py2exe with py2.7

Comment: Oh, ok see, I did the same thing on my windows computer and it worked as well with pyinstaller, maybe its just with Macs, I dont know. Thanks anyway though.